# MediaBrowserService quick-fired twice by MediaButtonReceiver?

Tags: android, android-mediasession

Using `MediaSessionCompat` with `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`. Suppose the service is not running. Now send a Media Button event, for example press the Next button on the headphones:

```
$ adb shell media dispatch next
```

And look at that! Not one but two Media Button events are being dispatched really! One is `ACTION_DOWN` and the other is `ACTION_UP`!

```
2020-12-16 00:29:29.627 11213-11213/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.media.Media
2020-12-16 00:29:29.665 2056-2383/? D/MediaSessionService: Sending KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=8068837, downTime=8068837, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=-1 } to the last known PendingIntent PendingIntent{96b5217: PendingIntentRecord{6cc38aa com.example.mediaservicetest broadcastIntent}}
2020-12-16 00:29:29.666 2056-2383/? D/MediaSessionService: Sending KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=8068837, downTime=8068837, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=-1 } to the last known PendingIntent PendingIntent{96b5217: PendingIntentRecord{6cc38aa com.example.mediaservicetest broadcastIntent}}
```

The `MediaButtonReceiver` is now binding `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` to promptly execute the callback and then it's releasing it. The sequence is:

- `onCreate()`
- `onBind()`
- `onSkipToNext() - // 1st event only*`
- `onUnbind()`
- `onDestroy()`

This is being called twice, really fast. So two instances of `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` were created, used and destroyed quickly, in turn.

*Except, only the first one was actually used as Media Session callback. `onSkipNext()` was only executed for `ACTION_DOWN` as `ACTION_UP` was filtered out by `MediaSessionCompat` before calling the Callback!

```
2020-12-16 00:29:29.672 10917-10917/com.example.mediaservicetest D/MediaBrowserCompat: Connecting to a MediaBrowserService.
2020-12-16 00:29:29.675 10917-10917/com.example.mediaservicetest I/main.MediaService.onCreate: *
2020-12-16 00:29:29.677 2056-2383/? D/MediaSessionService: Media button session is changed to com.example.mediaservicetest/foo (userId=0)
2020-12-16 00:29:29.686 10917-10917/com.example.mediaservicetest I/main.MediaService.onBind: *
2020-12-16 00:29:29.694 10917-10917/com.example.mediaservicetest I/main.MediaService$mediaSessionCallback.onSkipToNext: *

2020-12-16 00:29:29.695 10917-10917/com.example.mediaservicetest D/MediaBrowserCompat: Connecting to a MediaBrowserService.
2020-12-16 00:29:29.696 10917-10917/com.example.mediaservicetest I/main.MediaService.onUnbind: *
2020-12-16 00:29:29.696 10917-10917/com.example.mediaservicetest I/main.MediaService.onDestroy: *
2020-12-16 00:29:29.696 2056-2370/? D/MediaSessionService: Media button session is changed to null

2020-12-16 00:29:29.704 10917-10917/com.example.mediaservicetest I/main.MediaService.onCreate: *
2020-12-16 00:29:29.707 2056-2370/? D/MediaSessionService: Media button session is changed to com.example.mediaservicetest/foo (userId=0)
2020-12-16 00:29:29.734 10917-10917/com.example.mediaservicetest I/main.MediaService.onBind: *
2020-12-16 00:29:29.771 10917-10917/com.example.mediaservicetest I/main.MediaService.onUnbind: *
2020-12-16 00:29:29.771 10917-10917/com.example.mediaservicetest I/main.MediaService.onDestroy: *
2020-12-16 00:29:29.772 2056-2370/? D/MediaSessionService: Media button session is changed to null
```

Now for me it doesn't make much sense to instantiate this service twice (once for no reason). There is a `MediaSessionCompat` created in there, along with other init stuff. This quick-fire create-drop-create again caused me some pain managing all the player, focus, receivers, callbacks, notifications and what not!

So is this as designed, or some bug of the library? Or am I using it wrong?

Maybe @ianhanniballake would be interested in this. I could not find any explanation anywhere else. Thanks!

Comment: Note that your app can override [onMediaButtonEvent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.Callback#onmediabuttonevent) and do separate handling of `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` in whatever way you want. There's no way that `MediaButtonReceiver` could know if you want both events.

Comment: Thanks, Ian! I have assumed so far that only 1 action would result from a standard button press. One of Play, Pause, Next or Prev... or a custom action. 
I understand that this double-fire is to be expected, and my service should be made able to cope with that?

Comment: On Android, any button press consists of a button being pressed down (`ACTION_DOWN`) and being released (`ACTION_UP`). That's not unique to media buttons.

Comment: Acknowledged, but in this case the question is not about buttons but about media session callbacks such as next(). We press a next button to call it once but we launch 2 service instances for it :-)

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am now convinced this cannot work properly. If you send the `PLAY` command, the sequence is `onCreate()`->`onBind()`->`onPlay()`->`onUnbind()`->`onDestroy()`. So even if you call `startService()` inside `onPlay()`, the intent will only arrive later to create a new service instance, but your current service instance, together with your playback is destroyed on spot! As tested on Android 9, **sometimes** service will receive the start command before being destroyed, **but only sometimes**.

Comment: @RumburaK I'm experiencing exactly the same as you, media browser is disconnecting before I get the chance to start the service. As described here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver there are two options to handle media button events. Putting `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />` in my manifest and calling `ExtendedMediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSession, intent);` in `onStartCommand()` fixed it for me, because then the `MediaButtonReceiver` will start the service instead of connecting and disconnecting to it.